How can I prefetch the session of next auth globally? - with Nextjs page router
"Using NextAuth, I prefetch the session on the index.tsx page with SSR and inject it into _app.tsx. However, when refreshing the browser on other URLs, the session from NextAuth is not injected."
here is my code (SSR)
// index.tsx
export const getServerSideProps = (async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {

  const session = await getSession(ctx);
 
  return { props: { session: session } };
}) satisfies GetServerSideProps<{ session: Session | null }>;

and
// _app.tsx

<SessionProvider session={session}>
   
          <main className={cn(myFont.variable)}>
            <CommonLayout>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </CommonLayout>
          </main>
    </SessionProvider>

To prefetch the session globally, using getInitialProps in _app.tsx would work, but it's not recommended in Next.js, so I don't want to use it.
I considered handling it in middleware, but since middleware doesn't work on refresh, I don't think that's the solution.
How can I globally prefetch the session from NextAuth on the server and inject it, even on refresh?
I'm not currently employed. I'm a developer who wants to work in a company. Please, could you share how your company handles session management with NextAuth in a Next.js page router setup? I'm desperate to know. Please help...
